# displaying SOA environment versions and dependencies

Tags: web-services, web-applications, admin, soa, system-administration

In our SOA environment, we have a variety of environment such as dev, test, qa, uat, etc.  In each one of these environments we have various web and REST apps.

I'm looking for some kind of lightweight, web based, dashboard to show display what is running in all environments and if there is any version dependencies.

Hopefully, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

[So-Aware](http://www.tellagostudios.com/products/so-aware%E2%84%A2) is one application that can do it. There is a free express version to try.

Comment: I looked at briefly and found some interesting concerns of using it. Did you use it in your projects? Do you have any pros\cons?

Comment: I evaluated it but didn't find it very useful. But I was more interested in their performance test tool SO-Aware Test Workbench which requires this one to be installed as well. But the test tool had many limitations as well.